# Java - IntBuffer wrapping

Tags: java

I am reading a integer file using :

```
int len = (int)(new File(file).length());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte buf[] = new byte[len];
fis.read(buf);
IntBuffer up = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
```

But, it creates two copies of file in memory, 1) Byte Array copy 2) IntBuffer copy.

Is it possible to use the code in such a way thus it will create only one copy in memory?

Comment: You forgot about the copy in the disk cache. If you want to avoid copying it into Java memory, you can use a memory mapped file.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, below answer says, it does not create extra memory.

Comment: If you use a heap buffer it uses one copy in Java and one in the OS. If you use a memory mapped file there is just one copy *total* and it uses very little heap.

Comment: @alessandro: Peter is saying that using a memory-mapped file will avoid the (large) memory overhead from the `FileInputStream`, whereas the below answer is about the (tiny) overhead of the `IntBuffer`.

Comment: Good catch @PeterLawrey, I was wondering about how that aspect worked.

Comment: Do you really need the entire file in memory at once? I would look into reading it and processing it a piece at a time.

Comment: As EJP mentions, process the data as it is read can be more efficient as the OS will pre-read sequential read data and the two can efficiently happen in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadocs and the implementation from Oracle that I've looked at indicate that what you are saying is not true. The javadocs say that:

> public static ByteBuffer wrap(byte[] array)
>
> > Wraps a byte array into a buffer.
> >
> > The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

The code shows that the `array` passed into `ByteBuffer.wrap` is simply assigned as the internal array of the `ByteBuffer`. The `ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer` method simply shows the creation of an `IntBuffer` that uses the `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So, my method would actually screw it up, because overwriting buf[] would change the data in the IntBuffer up, right? And the data actually *isn't* in memory twice. Nice.

Comment: I also know what you just said. But, codes gives Out of memory error. Remove IntBuf line, code works nice.

Comment: From what I've seen, yes. That's not to say that it wouldn't be wiser for the OP to process the file data in more manageable chunks, as you suggested.

Comment: If you look at the `asIntBuffer()` implementation, it does _not_ do a copy; it just returns a view, which costs something like 100 bytes of memory.  It seems unlikely that your problem is with the `IntBuffer` taking up too much extra memory.

Comment: @alessandro, I've looked at this in the eclipse debugger. The reference id for the byte array that the IntBuffer implementation is using is identical to the reference id for the byte array read from the File. It is possible that you are just slightly over the max file size you can handle. Either use the `-Xmx` property to increase the JVM heap size, or re-write to process more manageable chunks of the file at a time. It probably is not wise to always try to read the whole file at once.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, javadoc also says that. But, it gives out of memory error !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you compare this with

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
IntBuffer ib = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size())
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();
```

This uses less than 1 KB of heap regardless of the file size.

BTW: This can be much faster than using a heap buffer because it doesn't need to assemble each `int` value from bytes.

Comment: mighty weird - no votes whatsoever, direct byte buffers asXXX() methods perform extremely well as they need not to convert anything at all. in nativeOrder get() can be cheap as any field load.

Comment: @bestsss Even you didn't vote for it. ;) I suspect many Java developers don't understand what memory mapping is doing.

Comment: but I never vote (look at my voting history), either way leaving positive comments is usually I do instead of voting.

Comment: Comments are better than upvote or downvoting IMHO. Keep it up. ;)